# Kotlin inner list filtering

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list like below,

```
ThreadsList-
    Thread1-
       Messages-
         Message1
           text="@"
         Message2
           text="hello"
    Thread2-
       Messages-
         Message1
           text="@"
         Message2
           text="hello"
         Message3
           text="hi"
```

I need to remove all messages inside each Thread that has the text "@"

I have tried the below code but it's not working as expected,

```
threadsList.filter { item ->
            item.messages.any { !it.text.equals("@")  }
        }
```

Comment: use Messages1 instead of any.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to be sure without seeing what kind of classes you use, but assuming you use data classes, it can be done similarly to this:

```
val cleanThreadList = threadList.map { thread ->
    thread.copy(
        messages = thread.messages.filter {
            it.text == "@"
        }
    )
}
```

**Edit (solution if your classes are mutable)**

If your classes are mutable then it's similar but a bit different:

```
threadList.forEach { thread ->
    thread.removeIf { message ->
      message.text != "@"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done by your code is to filter out the threads that contains all messages with text @. Since you have applied the filter method on threadsList, you will get a output threadsList in which all threads contains at least a non-@ message.

Now, what you have to do is perform some operation on all threads in the threadsList to filter out the messages with @ in it. It looks like this :

```
threadsList.onEach { thread ->
            thread.messages.filter { message ->
                message.text != "@"
            }
        }
```

and this will returned a threadsList which you need.